# New Radeon 7970 has lower resolution than old radeon 4670?

Tags: video, graphics-card, vga, dvi, amd-radeon

I have a VGA 22 inch 16:9 monitor, I always used my Radeon 4670 card and had a resolution for Windows 7 of 2048x1152.

Now I installed a radeon 7970, installed the drivers as well. The card only has DVI outputs, so I bought a DVI-to-VGA adapter. Now the max resolution is 1600x900?

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong? How is this possible?

Comment: What is the native resolution of you monitor (if it is 1600x900 then the new 7970 is doing the *right* thing and you need to select support for non standard resolutions.)

Answer (score 0):

The radeon 7970 does not have a lower resolution.  I have one running at 1920x1200 right now. It is probably the adapter causing the problem.  It is either the monitor or adapter.  I am using the DVI port to a monitor with a DVI port.  Although mine also has a mini-disport and hdmi port and both of them can also goto at least 1920x1200.

Comment: The monitor works fine if I plug it via VGA to another video card. I guess there's a problem with my adapter. Which kind of VGA to DVI adapter should I use to connect the VGA monitor into the DVI card and not loose resolution?

Comment: @Federico  What is the make and model of your monitor?